# Element-API: Access the first url of an asset array

Tags: url, php, plugin-elementapi, array

I have an asset field in my current project with the handle `postImage`, containing multiple image files. In my element-api endpoint, I wish to access the url of the first file only.

I tried the following code:

```
$imgs = $entry->postImage;
$imgUrl = $imgs[0]->getUrl();
```

The resulting console error message says:

```
500 (Call to a member function getUrl() on string)
```

Looping through the array works fine, but I don't want all image urls, just the first one.

It's probably very easy, but that ties a knot my brain. I don't understand where the array is being converted to a string, can anyone hint me to the solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to fetch the first image:

```
...
      'transformer' => function (Entry $entry) {
        foreach ($entry->images as $image) {
          $images[] = $image->url;
        }
        return [
          'images' =>  array_values($images)[0],
        ];
      },
...
```

or use [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

```
...
      'transformer' => function (Entry $entry) {
        foreach ($entry->images as $image) {
          $images[] = $image->url;
        }
        return [
          'images' =>  reset($images),
        ];
      },
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `reset()` works fine. When I use `array_values()` I get the following error: `500 (Undefined offset: 0)`. When I dump the entire array, the key `0` seems to be present. It works with `reset()` so I'm fine, but I'm curious why the other solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
'transformer' => function(craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
    $image = $entry->photos->one();

    return [
        'image' => $image ? $image->url : null,
    ];
},
```

**More info [here.](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api)**

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this myself, and I figured there had to be an easier built-in Craft solution rather than using pure PHP like HendrikEng suggested, and it turns out there is! Just use `$entry->assetsFieldHandle->one()->url`:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'entries.json' => function() {
            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'elementsPerPage' => 10,
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'blog'
                ],
                'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                    return [
                        'id' => $entry->id,
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'url' => $entry->url,
                        'mainImg' => $entry->mainImg->one()->url
                    ];
                }
            ];
        }
    ]
];
```